# How to get key of the item in laravel collection?

Tags: laravel

I pass a collection to the blade templating engine and in there I iterate over it. I want to display items position in the array. I thought of using items key, how do I extract it from the collections items?

Comment: show your blade code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No need to overcomplicate things.

```
// in your controller
return view()->with('collection', $collection);

// in your view
@foreach($collection as $index => $item)
  {{ $index }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: helo is that possible to get key without foreach?

Comment: $collection = Tracking::confirmedNotDel()
            ->groupBy('oppor_id')
            ->selectRaw('oppor_id, sum(logged_mins)/60 as logged_hours')
            ->get();


        $collection = collect($collection);
        $data       = $collection->where('oppor_id', $oppr->id);
        dd($data); //key of that object as i want to get row number